# How to do MediaCapture in UWP application but not store in local machine

Tags: camera, uwp

I am developing an UWP application with a camera feature, I have studied this sets of codes,
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit

And successfully developed a camera feature on my application. However, in my application, I wish to **not store the picture into my local machine** as the application is actually like a kiosk system whereby everyone will be using the same machine to take the picture.

What I am planning to do is actually to allow users to send the picture that they have taken to their own email address via the kiosk system. When they have taken a photo, a preview will be shown, and only if the user want to send the picture, then will the picture be **"save"**

[image: take picture]

The codes for my **take photo function** is something like this:

```
rivate async Task TakePhotoAsync()
    {

        var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

        Debug.WriteLine("Taking photo...");
        await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), stream);

        try
        {
            var file = await _captureFolder.CreateFileAsync("SimplePhoto.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            Debug.WriteLine("Photo taken! Saving to " + file.Path);

            var photoOrientation = CameraRotationHelper.ConvertSimpleOrientationToPhotoOrientation(_rotationHelper.GetCameraCaptureOrientation());

            await ReencodeAndSavePhotoAsync(stream, file, photoOrientation);
            Debug.WriteLine("Photo saved!");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // File I/O errors are reported as exceptions
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception when taking a photo: " + ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

And to get the **preview** of the picture will be:

```
private async Task GetPreviewFrameAsSoftwareBitmapAsync()
    {
        // Get information about the preview
        var previewProperties = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview) as VideoEncodingProperties;

        // Create the video frame to request a SoftwareBitmap preview frame
        var videoFrame = new VideoFrame(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, (int)previewProperties.Width, (int)previewProperties.Height);

        // Capture the preview frame
        using (var currentFrame = await _mediaCapture.GetPreviewFrameAsync(videoFrame))
        {
            // Collect the resulting frame
            SoftwareBitmap previewFrame = currentFrame.SoftwareBitmap;

            // Show the frame information
            FrameInfoTextBlock.Text = String.Format("{0}x{1} {2}", previewFrame.PixelWidth, previewFrame.PixelHeight, previewFrame.BitmapPixelFormat);


            // Create a SoftwareBitmapSource to display the SoftwareBitmap to the user
            var sbSource = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
            await sbSource.SetBitmapAsync(previewFrame);

            // Display it in the Image control
            PreviewFrameImage.Source = sbSource;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two ways:

1) "Better" one:

- Create a backend that sends email using [SmtpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Post your image from UWP to backend using [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient)

2) "Easier" one: launch [Mail app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/sending-email)

The downside is that users will be able to edit the message, receiver and things like that.

Also you can try to use SmtpClient directly from UWP client (may be now with .Net Standard 2.0 it would be possible but I guess no one yet tried) or [third-party open-source replacement](https://github.com/LightBuzz/SMTP-WinRT) (which might be a bit outdated as it was created for Windows 8) or even try to launch your backend as Windows Service on the client machine.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestions... but because I am still a student learning UWP, I am not very sure what SmtpClient is... and if I want to go with the first choice, will the picture still be stored on the local machine?

Comment: It will be good, if there is a sample for me the reference... if that is possible

Comment: SmtpClient will connect to SMTP server (the one that sends/receives emails).

Comment: If you need to make a simple app for learning just start with Mail App.
The code is pretty simple:
await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(new EmailMessage
{
// fill recipient and other properties
Attachments = // your image
});

Comment: Hi, I am trying out the SMTP server.... but when using System.Net.Mail, there is an error.. which says that namespace doesnt exist... I have added the references. but cant seem to solve the problem